# Create GRASS Mapset in QGIS 2.12

Tags: qgis, grass-gis

How do you create a new GRASS mapset in QGIS 2.12? The GRASS panel has only the Open GRASS Tools button.I don't see any way to actually create a GRASS mapset in QGIS.

Comment: Okay, I see. It is now accessed on the top menu bar by: Plugins->GRASS

Comment: You can post your comment as an answer

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same doubt using **QGIS 2.14.3**, since I was used to use the old GRASS toolbar where the Create and Open mapsets where included as buttons...

But as Jim himself answered, you just have to realize that those options are now in **Plugins > GRASS**

[image]