# v.rast.stats GRASS tool missing in QGIS 2.6.0 brighton

Tags: qgis, grass-gis

I'm still relatively new to the QGIS world, and the GRASS toolbox. I am trying to do zonal statistics on a shapefile I have in which I want to know the max and min elevation from my DEM. I have used the QGIS zonal statistics tool, but it only returns a count, sum and mean elevation value. After doing some research the v.rast.stats GRASS tool seems ideal. It is however missing from my toolbox, and I have no idea how to go about getting it.

Comment: 1. Are you sure you want to work with a version that is 6 versions behind the recent release? 2. Lots of GRASS functions aren't in the toolbox, and  might only be available through the GRASS plugin ... or worse ... only through GRASS itself. v.rast.stats is available through the plugin. But first you need to create a mapset ... good luck ;) see http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/198514/8202